# How do I restore my MySQL databases that were dumped from phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql

I recently did a clean install of Linux Mint 16 Petra on my laptop.

Before I wiped the old system, I did a backup of all my MySQL databases by going to the Export tab in phpMyAdmin and dumping all the databases into one file. I didn't use any compression.

Now, on the new system, in phpMyAdmin, when I go to the Import tab and try to upload the SQL file, I get this error:

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

... Of course no database is selected, I am trying to restore them.

I am not at all an expert in MySQL, I use it to support my web design projects, so I don't understand why this isn't working. It seems to me phpMyAdmin should be able to read from a file that phpMyAdmin created.

How do I restore my databases from the SQL dump file that I created?

Comment: Look into your dumped file and see if there is any `create database if not exist mysql` ... or similar lines. The dump should contain the data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used was to search the SQL file for everywhere that this text existed:

```
-- Database: `my_database_01`
```

And right under it, add the following lines:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `my_database_01`;
USE `my_database_01`;
```

I did this for each database in the SQL dump file, and then I was able to import and restore all databases using phpMyAdmin's import command.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your dump does not have the informations to create the database. Create the database first, then import the dump in that database.

Comment: The database file represents multiple databases. A dozen or so. I'm not sure I remember exactly what their names are. Is there no way to fix this with more of a batch process?

Comment: If there's no `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXIST` in your dump file, and if the old databases has been removed, then you have to re-create them by hand.